# How is minority interest accounted for when calculating net income

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, balance-sheet, cash-flow, income-statement

Reading around, I found that minority interest is defined as interest in a company controlled by a company other than the parent company.

Does that mean that anytime a company A becomes a shareholder of company B, those shares becomes part of minority interest? Does that include mutual funds as well? What's the point of this?

When I look at an income statement, I see that "net income" is equal to "net income to company" minus "minority interest in earnings". Looking at the cashflow statements, I see that the net income represented there is the net income to company minus minority interest in earnings. Where does the latter go? Surely, the minority owners don't get a share of the income.

Answer (score 1):

> When I look at an income statement, I see that "net income" is equal to "net income to
> company" minus "minority interest in earnings". Looking at the cashflow statements, I see
> that the net income represented there is the net income to company
> minus minority interest in earnings. Where does the latter go?

The rest goes into another line. See, this line "net income" allows you to evaluate the income OF THE COMPANY - if a company has a TON of interest earnings (hugh cash reserves, investments in other companies that pay a dividend) then unless you remove those (and keep them in another line item) they can turn a loosing company into a profitable one on paper. This is nice, but why keep the business around then ;) This is why they are removed - so to be able to evaluate the business of the company operations, without being overshadowed or influenced by investment income.

Answer (score 0):

If A owns 90% of B's voting shares, it controls B.  The remaining 10% is the minority interest.  Minority interest does not apply if A owns 100% of B.

Comment: Though correct, I don't this fully answered the OP's question. You might want to explain how that 10% of B affects A's income statement (i.e., the income attributable to the 10% of B that A doesn't own is what shows up as minority interest income in A's income statement).